# Need assistance understanding Perl script

Tags: perl

can someone help me understand what this script does in, Perl?
I've edited out all sensitive info. and such connections to DB.

The user who made this once, is probably dead by now, and we need it in a migration project.

Thanks in advance. :)

---

### edl400ba.bat file:

---

```
@echo off
rem Script called from file_import.bat
rem Is called with default parameters
rem %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6
rem <filename> <db_login> <ftp_host> <ftp_user> <ftp-password> <ftp-catalog>
rem perl edl400ba.pl "%area%" %area% %ip% slf %name003% >> \temp\edl400ba.log

rem If Perl is installed below ORACLE_HOME must variable PERL5LIB be blanked
set PERL5LIB=
set PATH=C:\strawberry\perl\bin;%PATH%

perl edl400ba.pl "%area%" %2 %3 %4 %5 >> \temp\edl400ba.log
```

---

### edl400ba.pl file:

---

```
use Net::FTP;

$catalog=$ARGV[0] ; # e.g. %area%
$sqluser=$ARGV[1] ; # oracle connection string; user/user@user
#$sqluser="%area%" ;
$ftp_adr=$ARGV[2] ; # ftp server, ip adress
$ftp_user=$ARGV[3];
$ftp_pwd=$ARGV[4] ;
$loggfile="$catalog/proc/ftplog.$$" ;
$programname="EDL400BA" ;

$local_dir="%area%";
$read_catalog=$katalog . "/%area%" ;

chdir $catalog . "/" . $local_dir || die "could not cwd to $katalog . "/" . $local_dir \n";

$ftp = Net::FTP->new($ftp_adr, Debug => 0) or die "Can't start ftp\n";
$ftp->login($ftp_user,$ftp_pwd) or die "Login error: $ftp_user/$ftp_pwd";

$filecount=0;
foreach $file ($ftp->ls) {
if ($file =~ /^e.*/ ) {
$ftp->get($file) or die "Can't get the file $file\n";
$filecount++;
$cmd = "perl $catalog/script/load_edl400ba.pl $catalog $sqluser $file";
if ( system($cmd) == 0 ) {
$ftp->delete($file) or print "Couldn't delete the file: $file\n";
}
else {die "Error loading file: $file - ending.\n"};
rename $catalog . "/" . $local_dir . "/" . $file, $read_catalog . "/" . $file;
}
}

$ftp->quit || print "Error closing ftp (ignored)\n";

print "$filecount file(s) grabbed from the server $ftp_adr\n";
```

---

### edl400ba_load file:

---

```
CATALOG=$1
USER=$2
FILE1=$3
GRNS_IN=$CATALOG /%area%
ORACLE_SID=egg;export $ORACLE_SID

# If the bad-file is found from f|r it shall be deleted
if test -r $CATALOG/bad/edl400ba.bad;
then rm $CATALOG/bad/edl400ba.bad;
fi;

# rows set to 64000 so that nothing is read in by accident
cd $CATALOG

sqlldr CONTROL=ctl/edl400ba.ctl, LOG=log/edl400ba, BAD=bad/edl400ba, DATA=$GRNS_IN/$FILe1, USERID=$USER, ERRORS=0,LOAD=99999, DISCARD=dsc/edl400ba ,DISCARDMAX=99999,ROWS=64000

# If the bad-filen has been created, an error message is given
if test -r $CATALOG/bad/edl400ba.bad;
then exit 9;
#else mv $GRNS_IN/$FILE1 $GRNS_OUT/$FILE1.read;
fi;
```

---

### pdi100ba.bat

---

```
@echo off
rem Script called from file_import.bat
rem Is called with default parameters (common format for multiple batch files, not all are relevant)
rem   %1        %2        %3            %4        %5            %6      %7
rem <filename> <db_login> <ftp_host> <ftp_user> <ftp-password> <ftp-catalog> <rapp_p1> 

set CATALOG=\egg_price\price

rem If Perl is installed below ORACLE_HOME must variable PERL5LIB be blanked
set PERL5LIB=
set PATH=C:\strawberry\perl\bin;%PATH%

perl pdi100ba.pl "/egg_pris/pris" %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 >> \temp\pdi100ba.log
```

---

## pdi100ba.pl

---

```
use Net::FTP;

$catalog=$ARGV[0] ;     # e.g. /egg_price/price
$sqluser=$ARGV[1] ;     # oracle connection string; user/user@user
$ftp_adr=$ARGV[2] ; # ftp server, ip adress
$ftp_user=$ARGV[3]; 
$ftp_pwd=$ARGV[4] ;
$loggfile="$catalog/proc/ftplog.$$" ;
$programname="PDI100BA" ;

$local_dir="grns_in/readin/readout";
$read_catalog=$catalog . "/grns_in/readin/readout" ;


chdir "$catalog/$local_dir" || die "could not cwd to $catalog/$local_dir \n";

$ftp = Net::FTP->new($ftp_adr, Debug => 0) or die "Can't start ftp\n";
$ftp->login($ftp_user,$ftp_pwd) or die "Login error: $ftpuser/$ftppwd";


$filecount=0;
foreach $file ($ftp->ls) {
    if ($file =~ /^k.*/ ) {
        $ftp->get($file) or die "Can't get the file $file\n";
        $filecount++;
        $cmd = "perl $catalog/script/load_pdi100ba.pl $catalog $sqluser $file";
        if ( system($cmd) == 0 ) {
            $ftp->delete($file) or print "Couldn't delete the file: $file\n";
        }
        else {die "Error loading file: $file - ending.\n"}; 
                rename $catalog . "/" . $local_dir . "/" . $file, $read_catalog . "/" . $file;
    }
}

$ftp->quit; 

print "$filecount file(s) grabbed from the server $ftp_adr\n";

Thanks in advance. :)
```

---

## pdi100ba_load

---

```
CATALOG=$1
USER=$2
FILE1=$3
GRNS_IN=$CATALOG/grns_in/readin/readout
ORACLE_SID=price;export $ORACLE_SID

# If the bad-file is found from f|r it shall be deleted 
if test -r $CATALOG/bad/pdi100ba.bad;
then rm $CATALOG/bad/pdi100ba.bad;
fi;

# rows set to 64000 so that nothing is read in by accident
cd $CATALOG
echo  "FILENAME constant \"$FILE1\" )"    > ctl/pdi100ba_del2
cat ctl/pdi100ba_del1 ctl/pdi100ba_del2 > ctl/pdi100ba.ctl

sqlldr CONTROL=ctl/pdi100ba.ctl, LOG=log/pdi100ba, BAD=bad/pdi100ba, DATA=$GRNS_IN/$FILE1, USERID=$USER, ERRORS=0,LOAD=99999, DISCARD=dsc/pdi100ba ,DISCARDMAX=99999,ROWS=64000

# If the bad-filen has been created, an error message is given
if test -r $CATALOG/bad/pdi100ba.bad;
then exit 9;
#else mv $GRNS_IN/$FILE1 $GRNS_OUT/$FILE1.read;
fi;
```

---

## pdi200ba.bat

---

```
@echo off
rem Script called from file_import.bat
rem Is called with default parameters (common format for multiple batch files, not all are relevant)
rem   %1        %2        %3            %4        %5            %6      %7
rem <filename> <db_login> <ftp_host> <ftp_user> <ftp-password> <ftp-catalog> <rapp_p1> 

set CATALOG=\egg_price\price

rem If Perl is installed below ORACLE_HOME must variable PERL5LIB be blanked
set PERL5LIB=
set PATH=C:\strawberry\perl\bin;%PATH%

perl pdi200ba.pl "/egg_price/price" %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 >> \temp\pdi200ba.log
```

---

## pdi200ba.pl

---

```
    use Net::FTP;

    $CATALOG=$ARGV[0] ;     # e.g. /egg_price/egg
    $sqluser=$ARGV[1] ;     # oracle connection string; user/user@user
    $ftp_adr=$ARGV[2] ; # ftp server, ip adress
    $ftp_user=$ARGV[3]; 
    $ftp_pwd=$ARGV[4] ;

    $loggfile="$CATALOG/proc/ftplog.$$" ;
    $programname="PDI200BA" ;

    $local_dir="grns_in/readin/readout";
    $read_CATALOG=$CATALOG . "/grns_in/readin/readout" ;


    chdir "$CATALOG/$local_dir" || die "could not cwd to $CATALOG/$local_dir\n";


    $ftp = Net::FTP->new($ftp_adr, Debug => 0) or die "Kan ikke starte ftp\n";
    $ftp->login($ftp_user,$ftp_pwd) or die "Feil ved innlogging: $ftp_user/$ftp_pwd";

    $filecount=0;
    foreach $file ($ftp->ls) {
        if ($file =~ /^a.*/ ) {
            $ftp->get($file) or die "Can't start $file\n";
            $filecount++;
            $cmd = "perl $CATALOG/script/load_pdi200ba.pl $CATALOG $sqluser $file";
            if ( system($cmd) == 0 ) {
                $ftp->delete($file) or print "Couldn't delete the file: $file\n";
            }
            else {die "Error loading file: $file - ending.\n"}; 
                    rename $CATALOG . "/" . $local_dir . "/" . $file, $read_CATALOG . "/" . $file;
        }
    }

    $ftp->quit; 

    print "$filecount file(s) grabbed from the server $ftp_adr\n";
```

---

**# pdi200ba_load**

---

```
CATALOG=$1
USER=$2
FILE1=$3
GRNS_IN=$CATALOG/grns_in/readin/readout
ORACLE_SID=price;export $ORACLE_SID

# If the bad-file is found from f|r it shall be deleted 
if test -r $CATALOG/bad/pdi200ba.bad;
then rm $CATALOG/bad/pdi200ba.bad;
fi;

# rows set to 64000 so that nothing is read in by accident
cd $CATALOG
echo  "FILENAME constant \"$FILE1\" )"    > ctl/pdi200ba_del2
cat ctl/pdi200ba_del1 ctl/pdi200ba_del2 > ctl/pdi200ba.ctl

sqlldr CONTROL=ctl/pdi200ba.ctl, LOG=log/pdi200ba, BAD=bad/pdi200ba, DATA=$GRNS_IN/$FILE1, USERID=$USER, ERRORS=0,LOAD=99999, DISCARD=dsc/pdi200ba ,DISCARDMAX=99999,ROWS=64000

#  If the bad-filen has been created, an error message is given
if test -r $CATALOG/bad/pdi200ba.bad;
then exit 9;
#else mv $GRNS_IN/$FILE1 $GRNS_OUT/$FILE1.read;
fi;
```

Comment: This seems to be pretty messy. Hiring someone who understands Perl would be the best option.

Comment: You're right. Do you know anywhere we can rent someone who understands perl?

Comment: jobs.perl.org used to be a good place to advertise Perl jobs.

Comment: I have used freelancer.com, there  is coders of any kind

Answer (score 1):

A quick overview:

the file you called ".bad"-file

1. makes a conneciton to an ftp server,
2. looks for files on the server (using command `ls`),
3. picks out only the files with a filename starting with the  "e." (pattern `/^e.*/`),
4. downloads the files one by one and runs yet another perl command on them called `load_edl400ba.pl`.

Maybe you can be more specific about what you already know and what you still need to understand?

Comment: Hi, just an understanding of what's going on. There's a migration project now, moving this script from a customers IT- partner til ours. We need to understand what changes we need to make, to make it work. I can add the other scripts too also. 

Thanks :)

Comment: +Bjelli, 

changed the post now. Please help! :D thanks